# tcmuploadassembly.exe location?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

Where can I download  "tcmuploadassembly.exe"  for 2013 SP1 ?

I added some extra text here, because Stack Exchange kept complaining about my one sentence question.

Comment: Should be under [Tridion home]\bin\client, where the tom.net dlls are

Answer (score 6):

The TcmUploadAssembly.exe is a tool developers use to upload their compiled .Net Template Building Blocks to the Tridion server.

While many people prefer to run it at the [command line](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-0641B182-7472-4B2E-AF9B-426F0AEAC1CD), (login required) or as a [post-build event inside the Visual Studio solution](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-CE7CA166-3263-4186-ABF1-8DD1A7882F63), one of the nicer solutions is the [Visual Studio Assembly Upload extension](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/AssemblyUploader.aspx) on TridionWorld.

To debug your templates you can [attach to the TcmTemplateDebugHost](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-2FCC6253-71C7-4643-A1C0-0E2C38FB3358).

Finally, it is always recommended to store your .Net TBB Sourcecode in an external Source code Control System (SCCS) such as Git, SVN, or TFS since only the compiled assembly is uploaded into Tridion.